# Add symbol to chapter header

Tags: titles, chapters

I would like to add the "|" symbol or vertical line, to the chapter header so that it will look like this:

[image]

Here is the original code:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Decision Trees}
Text
\chapter{Main}

\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\chapterlabel #1` is the place for inserting the vertical line. `\chapterlabel` is either empty for unnumbered chapters or it contains the chapter number including a trailing space.

A vertical line can be added by `\vrule`. The width can be configured by keyword `width`: `\vrule width 1pt`. The height and depth depend on the height and depth of the line and may vary across chapters. A constant rule is available as `$|$`. The latter in the bold version is used in the following example:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}%
                  \ifx\chapterlabel\empty
                  \else
                    \chapterlabel $\boldsymbol{|}$ %
                  \fi
                  #1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Decision Trees}
Text
\chapter{Main}

\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Page 3:

> [image: Page 3]

Page 7:

> [image: Page 7]